# Show 2 options and then "and x more" (select2)

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I am using select2 on my website. The user is able to select about 30 options, when all is selected it looks kinda clumsy and takes up a lot of space.

So when more than 3 options is selected, I'd like it to list the first 3 options, and then show "and x more".

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Please include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. Thanks!

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea what to do, I don't really code myself, I looked at the options on the github page, but there didn't seem to be any option for enabling this

Comment: I don't think that select2 have this option. But you can try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/zA23k/215/. Maybe the root of you problem could be UX.

Comment: Pablo. I don't exactly see how I would use that.
I seem to have temporarily fixed it with this:
`max-height: 6em;
overflow-y: scroll;`
on .select2-selection--multiple

This way it doesn't take up too much space, but I'd still prefer if it could say "and x more"

Comment: I've chosen to replace select2 with bootstrap-select. It seems to do a better job.

Answer (score 0):

Needed it for a project so I just worked on it:

```
$("select").select2().on('change', function() {
    var select = $(this);
    var container = select.prev('.select2-container-multi').find('.select2-choices');
    var choices = container.find('.select2-search-choice');
    var val = select.val();
    var last = container.find('.select2-search-choice:last').clone();
    var lastVal = (!!val && val[val.length - 1].length > 30) ? val[val.length - 1].substring(0,30)+'...' : val[val.length - 1];
    if (val.length >= 2) {
        container.find('.select2-search-choice').remove();
        last.find('div').text(lastVal + ' + ' + (val.length - 1));
        last.prependTo(container);
        container.on('click', 'a', function(){
            container.find('.select2-search-choice').remove();
            select.val('');
        });
    }
});
```

**Note** that this is based on the old version of the select2 plugin.